Pooled Dataset from Multiple Chain Imputations in R
After running MICE on specific variables in R, and using m= 5, I am trying to get a pooled dataset that will have the average of those 5 imputations.

imp <- mice(dt_imp, predictorMatrix = pred, method = meth,m=5,seed = 123) # this is my imputation

complete_data <- complete(imp) # This code is working but I discovered that this is taking the first imputed dataset, I want to get the average of the imputed datasets.

pooled_data= pool(imp) # this is giving error (Error in as.mira(object) :
as.mira() cannot convert class 'mids' into 'mira'. Use with() instead.)

I even tried it with, with() nothing is working.


Note: all my variables are categorical and as.factor
I am trying to get a pooled dataset from the imputed datasets with same number of observations as my initial dataset.

I know this post is 4 months old, but hopefully this answer will help.
With multiple imputation, you don't pool your imputed datasets into a single dataset with the averages. Pooling takes place after analysis - you analyze each imputed dataset separately, and pool the results from each analysis to get an idea for the variability of whatever it is you're modeling (e.g. you would look at how your model parameters change across your different imputed datasets).
Remember that the only difference between your imputed datasets is the estimated values for missing data; everything else will be the same. The purpose of multiple imputation is to see how different estimates impact the results of your analysis, not to create a single averaged estimate for each missing value. I recommend looking up "Rubin's rules" for more information.
The top answer to this post may also be of interest: Multiple Imputed datasets - pooling results
